# Como criar uma variável através da resposta digitada pelo usuário em Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Por exemplo, podemos usar este código para atribuir o **valor** a uma variável:

```
idade = input('Digite sua idade: ')
```

O que eu gostaria de saber é, se ao invés de atribuir um **valor** a uma variável é possível criar uma variável nomeando ela com um valor digitada pelo usuário?

Comment: Não percebi bem o quer dizer com "criar uma variável com uma resposta digitada pelo usuári" podes dar um exemplo sff

Comment: O que o usuário escrever se transforme em uma variável. Por exemplo: se o usuário escrever "João" - então uma variável chamada "João" seja criada.

Comment: Acho que dá pra tentar construir algo usando o [`getattr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#getattr). Mas, só por curiosidade: qual é a/o vantagem/objetivo de fazer isso? Não é mais fácil e prático simplesmente utilizar um [dicionário](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)?

Comment: Você quer armazenar o valor "João" na variável, é isso?

Comment: A variável com acentos não é boa prática

Comment: Você pode usar o comando [`exec`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec) para criar a variável e atribuir um valor qualquer a ela, mas não tenho certeza se isso seria uma boa prática, do ponto de vista de segurança

Comment: @Math  não. Veja só: nome_da_variável = valor_da_variável --- o que o usuário escreve com o código input geralmente é usado para atribuir o valor_da_variável certo. O que eu quero é usar a resposta digitada pelo usuário para criar uma variável (nome_da_variável).

Comment: @Luiz Vieira por enquanto minha duvida é simplesmente um estudo

Comment: Mas a variável é só um nome para referenciar uma posição de memória, em tempo de execução o nome da variável é completamente irrelevante, isso só importar para o programador. A não ser que eu esteja entendendo errado não vejo a vantagem disso.

Comment: Obrigado a todos pelos comentários.
Considerei a questão respondida com o comentário do @Math
>Mas a variável é só um nome para referenciar uma posição de memória, em tempo de execução o nome da variável é completamente irrelevante, isso só importar para o programador. A não ser que eu esteja entendendo errado não vejo a vantagem disso

Answer (score 4):

Como os colegas informaram essa pode não ser a melhor maneira de resolver o seu problema, mas no python você pode atribuir uma variável com o valor da outra sim com o `exec`.

Vale lembrar que isso não vai alterar o nome da variável e sim criar uma outra a partir do valor digitado.

Segue exemplo:

```
foo = "bar" //criando a variável foo com o valor "bar"
exec(foo + " = 'Valor da variavel bar'")
print (bar) // saída: Valor da variavel bar
```

Comment: muito interessante essa abordagem!

Answer (score 4):

Se a ideia é usar [variáveis variáveis](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.variables.variable.php) você terá que usar um dicionário para fazer isto, assim como mencionado pelo @LuizVieira. Entretanto, não e a mesma coisa que o PHP e eu não conheço um mecanismo em Python que possa fazer isto.

Veja um pequeno exemplo:

```
meudic = {}
varnome = "variavelDoGato"
meudic[varnome] = "meow"
print(meudic["variavelDoGato"])
```

Saída:

> meow

Fonte:
[How do I create a variable number of variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1373192/5429980)

Answer (score 3):

A variável é só um nome para referenciar um objeto que ocupa uma posição de memória. Em tempo de execução o nome da variável é completamente irrelevante já que ninguém estará a visualizando nesse dado momento.

O nome da variável é importante para o programador desenvolver a sua lógica corretamente, portanto não há motivos para trocar seu nome em tempo de execução.